# Jquery Mobile set cache to expire

Tags: jquery, caching, jquery-mobile, browser-cache

I'm using jquery mobile and I'm placing `data-dom-cache="true"` to cache some pages. What i wanted to know is whether it is possible to add an age to that cache for e.g. I want that page to be cache only for 2 minutes. Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/new-attribute-dom-cache-expires-120